# Save data coming from UI as drafts using spring and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have to make the backend system in spring boot which is able to save drafts, once the draft is approved the data has to be saved in their respective tables. Let's say i have the tables student and subjects.
Once a student fills his details and it gets approved the data has to flow through student table and then it's multiple subjects that he filled should be saved in the subjects table.
Also i have to make sure that draft data should be stored in such a manner that if UI asks for that draft, i should be able to return it in proper json format

Comment: You can store the data in the tables students and subjects and keep a column named 'Status' in students table , value of which can be Draft or Approved. Is there something , that you will delete this record if it is not approved?

Comment: yes we have to delete it incase it is not approved, even user will have the option to delete the current draft and start with a new one @Harmandeep Singh Kalsi

Comment: Okay so , I think that should be fine , have a status field in the table and initially make it draft . So when users deletes first check what is the status of the record , and accordingly respond . if it is draft delete it and if it is not show a message saying , you can not delete , it is approved. Hope it makes sense . Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i was thinking maybe i should keep the draft data coming from UI in my master student table and master subjects table along with the original data but will keep a flag to distinguish b/w draft and live data, in this way if user wants to submit a draft i then only have to change the flag from draft to approved.

Comment: There will be redundancy of the data in this way I believe. Because ultimately once it is approved , you will not need draft one right?

Comment: yes but in this case i simply have to change the value of flag from draft to approved once approval is done. And also editing the approved data i believe will be easier (if in future we have to do editing of approved data)

Comment: Sure emRyder , good luck !

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve this problem in a lot of diferent ways. The simple and classic way (depending on the size of your data and if you don't need cache mechanisms) is create `Entities` to represent the `Draft` and the same for `Student` and `Subject`. As long you create these representations you will be able to manage this in your back-end (create, find, remove, update etc.).

I suggest you to use Spring Boot, using `Rest Controllers`, creating endpoints like: `POST createDraft` and so on.

You can find a lot of tutorials [like this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

And then you could use VueJS SPA for your front-end, consuming you spring boot back-end.